# Modelling the effect of a continuous (linear) predictor on a non-von Mises circular data

Tags: r, regression, circular-statistics

I am working with circular data (n=800+) representing the time of animal activity in radians, scaled between 0 and 2π. My objective is to determine the influence of a linear predictor, specifically the distance to human settlements, on animal activity. However, the circular data does not conform to a von Mises distribution (as indicated by Watson's Test for the von Mises Distribution: `Test Statistic: 0.8721, Level 0.05, Critical Value: 0.079`). Consequently, I am unable to proceed with the `lm.circular.cl` function from the `circular` package. Instead, I have opted for the `circGLM` function from the `circglmbayes` package, assuming its analogy to normal GLMs and potential suitability for non-parametric distribution, with normally distributed residuals.

Here is my implementation and data with the first 100 values:

```
library(circglmbayes)

# Circular data representing animal activity times
act_in_rad <- as.circular(c(
  5.817546, 5.836599, 2.185734, 2.673917, 1.973386, 2.531236, 1.706496, 1.377937, 1.936006, 5.648758,
  6.034767, 0.00283616, 0.3900084, 4.066181, 5.406448, 1.859576, 4.389721, 0.6802421, 0.4525493, 1.372992,
  0.3878994, 1.140064, 3.91281, 2.906191, 4.415465, 1.0168, 0.2852886, 5.721844, 4.672465, 4.966771, 4.694499,
  5.366887, 5.768313, 5.782203, 5.643522, 1.964223, 5.001241, 0.5446882, 1.693333, 5.232061, 1.734566, 1.581777,
  1.202241, 1.70875, 1.267545, 1.958114, 6.12007, 5.260422, 5.908594, 0.2616539, 0.1556979, 1.554507, 4.78053,
  5.59298, 2.062397, 6.018841, 4.636613, 5.949537, 6.225953, 0.7280932, 5.667448, 5.465789, 0.6952228, 0.9264062,
  1.108575, 6.280713, 5.825982, 0.2318379, 0.2721986, 0.5755223, 0.5250532, 5.077963, 0.1402081, 0.3792455,
  5.168429, 0.07374016, 4.381649, 4.72337, 1.460622, 0.74671, 2.204278, 2.048289, 1.945679, 1.297652, 5.121305,
  5.029457, 5.780821, 3.432335, 0.2604177, 4.958553, 0.6552984, 5.055419, 0.4252058, 2.248202, 0.153589,
  1.780381, 2.172353, 2.478877, 1.836886, 5.583599), 
template = "clock24", modulo = "asis", zero = 0, type = "angle", units = "radians", rotation = "clock")

# Predictor variable (distance to human settlements)
dist <- c(
  1467, 1467, 615, 615, 615, 615, 615, 2330, 2330, 2330, 2330, 2330, 2330, 3293, 3293, 3293, 3293, 3293, 3293,
  3293, 3293, 3293, 3293, 3293, 3293, 3293, 3293, 3293, 3293, 3293, 3293, 3293, 3293, 3293, 3293, 3293, 3293,
  3293, 2271, 2271, 2271, 2271, 2271, 2271, 1191, 1191, 1191, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 309, 309, 309,
  2996, 2996, 2996, 2996, 2996, 2996, 2996, 2996, 2996, 2996, 2996, 2996, 2996, 2996, 2996, 2996, 2996, 2996,
  2996, 2996, 2996, 2315, 2315, 2315, 2315, 2315, 760, 760, 760, 760, 760, 1864, 1864, 1864, 1864, 1864, 1864,
  1864, 1864, 1864, 1342, 1342, 1218, 1218, 1218, 1218, 1218)

# Fitting circGLM model
cGLM <- circGLM(act_in_rad ~ dist)

# Results
Bayesian circular GLM 

Call:
circGLM(formula = act_in_rad ~ dist)

MCMC run for 1000 its, 1000 used. 

Coefficients:
            Estimate         SD         LB          UB
Intercept -0.1099459 0.06118159 -0.2297523  0.01014120
Kappa      0.8167009 0.06231542  0.7066163  0.94700764
dist      -0.1113824 0.03179422 -0.1735515 -0.05044825

DIC:  2855.104 
WAIC: 2855.108
```

The residuals are not quite von Mises distributed, but the departure doesn't seem severe both from the test (`Test Statistic: 0.3162, Level 0.05, Critical Value: 0.101`) and visualisation plot.

Am I correct in interpreting the results this way: The distance estimate is -0.1113824, which means for every unit increase in distance, animal activity shifts from origin (0, I assume, which is midnight) by -0.1113824 radians, i.e. it shifts by 25 min 32 seconds from midnight counter-clockwise? Here, the intercept is already at -0.1099459, which means the new origin would be 0 - 0.1099459, i.e. 25:12 before midnight?

I also tried executing the `predict.circGLM` function for the same dist values as given above, but I don't quite understand the results. It seems rather homogenous.

```
# Predicted values:

-3.239242, -3.239242, -3.222492, -3.222492, -3.222492, -3.222492, -3.222492, -3.243721, -3.243721, 
-3.243721, -3.243721, -3.243721, -3.243721, -3.245948, -3.245948, -3.245948, -3.245948, -3.245948, 
-3.245948, -3.245948, -3.245948, -3.245948, -3.245948, -3.245948, -3.245948, -3.245948, -3.245948, 
-3.245948, -3.245948, -3.245948, -3.245948, -3.245948, -3.245948, -3.245948, -3.245948, -3.245948, 
-3.243523, -3.243523, -3.243523, -3.243523, -3.243523, -3.243523, -3.23644, -3.23644, -3.23644, 
-3.15394, -3.15394, -3.15394, -3.15394, -3.15394, -3.15394, -3.15394, -3.19394, -3.19394, -3.19394, 
-3.245414, -3.245414, -3.245414, -3.245414, -3.245414, -3.245414, -3.245414, -3.245414, -3.245414, 
-3.245414, -3.245414, -3.245414, -3.245414, -3.245414, -3.245414, -3.245414, -3.245414, -3.245414, 
-3.245414, -3.245414, -3.243672, -3.243672, -3.243672, -3.243672, -3.243672, -3.227994, -3.227994,
-3.227994, -3.227994, -3.227994, -3.241818, -3.241818, -3.241818, -3.241818, -3.241818, -3.241818, 
-3.241818, -3.241818, -3.241818, -3.238116, -3.238116, -3.23677, -3.23677, -3.23677, -3.23677, -3.23677
```

My understanding of circular statistics is very limited. Can someone please validate the choice of the test and interpretation or provide some alternate way to test the effect? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by a "linear" predictor for circular data? // Why do you care whether the data are approximated by a Von Mises distribution?  That's irrelevant.  What matters is how the *errors* in the prediction might be distributed.

Comment: Hi @whuber thanks for the comment. By a "linear" predictor for circular data, I just mean a linear regressor for a circular response variable. // Something from the `lm.circular` documentation: _The model assumes that a circular response variable theta has a von Mises distribution with concentration parameter kappa, and mean direction related to a vector of linear predictor variables..._ so I thought von Mises was an assumption for the circular response variable. Anyway, I tried executing `lm.circular.cl` but couldn't directly get the residuals from the results to check. Any workaround?

Comment: Your quotation is explaining that the response variable, *conditional on the "vector of ... predictor variables,"* has a von Mises distribution.  Unless the predicted value is constant, this means the response variable itself does *not* have a von Mises distribution.  As far as obtaining residuals goes, you will have to consult the documentation or the source code.

Comment: I calculated the residuals manually. There is a lot of deviation from the actual values, and the residuals don't fit the distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because we are dealing with circular GLM's, the interpretation is not exactly as you expect it to be coming from linear GLM's. The link function here is the arctangent function (specifically `atan2`), and each coefficient is about the *slope* at the midpoint of that link function, which is at the 0 value of the predictor. By the way, this means that the model changes if you change the mean of the predictor, so often, standardization is recommended (looking at the predictions, it seems likely that you did not standardize yet).

Either way, the correct interpretation of the current model is:

*'At `dist` zero, the slope of the counter-clockwise change of the direction of animal activity is -0.1113824' when starting at the intercept at -0.1099459.*

If you don't mind a frequentist interpretation of the Bayesian Confidence Interval, you could add that:

*'zero is not in the confidence interval, so there is a significant effect of distance on direction of animal activity'*.

If I understand your context correctly, you can replace 'direction of animal activity' with 'time of the day that animal activity occurs' in the above interpretations.

Second, the predicted values seem correct, as they are the same when the inputs are the same. Often, if the directions are somewhat close together, the resulting predictions will fall mostly on the same range of the circle, around the mean direction of the observations, which in your case seems to be around midday.

Third, @whuber is correct that it's the residuals which should be von Mises-distributed, which is by the way what `circGLM` assumes as well. However, this matches with your approach, where you reject von Mises on the data without a predictor, but are still able to use the GLM. It's probably not a perfect fit on the residuals either, but the problems that generates are often not severe, while the complexity of relaxing that assumption is quite large. Hence, I think the GLM model could be a good fit for your problem.

Lastly, make sure to have a look at the plots generated by this package, using `plot(model)` for example. See `?plot.circGLM` for more, as this should help the interpretation, especially `plot(model, type='predict')`.

Full disclosure: I wrote this package.